# How many tasks should I use in .net according to the processor cores?

Tags: parallel-processing

I have a Pentium(R) Dual Core CPU E5200 2/50GHz.

It means that I have two cores. I have developed a parallel approach for an Intelligent algorithm.

I am doing a data parallelism by splitting the data set into X parts (X = number of .net Tasks). I am giving a group of data to each task.

I have tried using 2, 4, 8 and 16 tasks and I couldnt see any improvement in the algorithm. Of course that parallel approach of the algorithm is faster then the serial (original) one but starting from 2 tasks up to 16 there is no improvement. They all perform same. I dont know weather Im doing something wrong or maybe the CPU capacity is that much (and it doesnt matter what the number of tasks is ?).

In order to be more practical, here is some of my code that describes what Im actually doing:

```
  while (iteration < SOMState.Map.numbOfIterations)
        {
            netTasks.Clear(); // netTaks contains all the tasks that I creat inside the loop
            int tdd = 0;
            foreach (TasksData td in tasks)
            {
                int val = tdd;
                Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => startParallelMethod(iteration, tasks[val], SOMState.dataset.GroupedData[val], tasks[val].Map, SOMState.dataset.GroupedDataDictionary[val]));
                netTasks.Add(t1);
                tdd++;
            }

         await Task.WhenAll(netTasks);
         // do some stuff here
         iteration++;
        }


    public void startParallelMethod(int iteration,TasksData task,List<GenerateDataSetFromCSV.Vector> dataset, Map map, Dictionary<int, List<Double>> dictionaryDataset)
    {
        // it performs some processing in here
    }
```

Does one task use one core of processor?

Environment.ProcessorCount gives me 2. Does this mean that whatever is the number of tasks, still the performance will be as if I have used 2 tasks ?!

**UPDATE:**

For those who may be interested, I have answered to my own question.

Comment: Are you not able to use framework facilities such as `Parallel.ForEach`? Is there a reason why you think you'll do a better job of partitioning the work between tasks manually?

Comment: Just a hint: If your code is CPU bound you could use Parallel.For / Parallel.Foreach and let the runtime decide how far it should parallelize

Comment: Hmm interesting. Well, I need to check and see whether I can use Parallel.Foreach in my code or not.  Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: @Linky I can not use Parallel.For because I have a lot of shared variables that I use inside the loop. It is very complicated to change the code and adabt it to work with Parallel.For

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As follow-up to the comments: Unless I'm missing something, instead of

```
int tdd = 0;
foreach (TasksData td in tasks)
{
    int val = tdd;
    Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => startParallelMethod(iteration, tasks[val], SOMState.dataset.GroupedData[val], tasks[val].Map, SOMState.dataset.GroupedDataDictionary[val]));
    netTasks.Add(t1);
    tdd++;
}
```

you could write (please note: pseudo code!)

```
Parallel.For(0, tasks.Length, val => { 
    startParallelMethod(iteration, tasks[val], SOMState.dataset.GroupedData[val], tasks[val].Map, SOMState.dataset.GroupedDataDictionary[val])
});
```

As your original code uses await you could wrap the Parallel.For code in a Task.Run() and its behavior should be the same outside the method (although this is, same as your initial sample, far away from best practice on using async-await).

Nevertheless - with few changes you should be able to let the Runtime decide how many tasks to use.

Comment: I think this is the same because "tasks" is the number of tasks that Im going to use(user defined). According to tasks.count I split my huge data set into tasks.count groups. Then, each group of data (SOMState.dataset.GroupedData[val]) is given as a parameter to the method startParallelMetho. This method is going to process its group of data given as parameter. If I have n tasks it means that I will call startParallelMethod n times with n different data sets(groups of data).

Comment: To be more clear, startParallelMethod will be called tasks.count times with tasks.count different data from tasks.count .net tasks.

Comment: maybe I'm not getting the original question correctly: It seems that in the original code startPArallelMethod is executed in Parallel by using Task.Factory.StartNew. All In all tasks.Count Tasks running startParallelMethod would be started. Is this correct so far?

Instead of this, using Parallel.For would do pretty much the same - running startParallelMethod task.Count times - except it takes care of how many to start/run concurrently. Isn't this was the question was about?

Comment: yes everything you said is true. My problem is: what should "the number of tasks" be, which in other words means "Into how many groups should I split my original data set"?I have a data set(SOMState.dataset) and in order to parallelize my algorithm I am splitting it into tasks.count groups (SOMState.dataset.GroupedData). If I have split my original data set into 4 groups.I am calling startParallelmethod 4 times from 4 different tasks. In this way I am trying to perform the algorithm faster by splitting my data set into 4 .net tasks. Each task will perform a sub group of original data set

Comment: I understood everything you said and I will use your suggestion for that. My issue is the number of subgroups (of original data set) that I should use. If I use n groupd than the Parallel.for will loop n times! That`s my problem. I think this is depended on the number of cores a processor has. Maybe I should be using Environment.ProcessorCount groups of data. This means that Parallel.For loop will be loop Environment.ProcessorCount times.

Comment: IMHO you don't need to create subgroups. As long as it's CPU bound and you do calculations in startParallelMethod you can pass the whole IEnumerable to PFor and let it decide. If it's ok for you I'm gonna update the answer

Comment: is the code comment "//do some stuff here" the region where you're creating the next chunk?

Comment: Yes in "//do some stuff here" I process the data sets(sub groups) given as parameter. I tried your suggestion in a core i7 with 6 sub groups of data and it is working faster (similar to my first written approach but a little bit faster).

Comment: I have tried giving all the data set to Parallel.For but it takes more time. If I give all the data set than there will be no loops inside parallel.for. Or maybe I should loop through the data inside the data set instead of looping through tasks.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the creation of your tasks object? 

One other thing: Is your method really CPU bound? If it contains IO Operations PFor likely creates to many tasks by trying to bring the CPU to full load.

Comment: I updated and as you can see in the updates splitting the data set into Environment.ProcessorCount groups performs fastest. P.S. I am using Parallel.For as you suggested but still with spitted data set

Answer (score 0):

**For those who may be interested:**

After performing some experiments, here are the results using a core i7 processor. It shows up that using 6 tasks (the number of cores of processor) performs fastest. When I say using 6 tasks I also mean splitting my data set into 6 groups; each group will be given to one task. We can also use Parallel.For as the answer which I accepted suggests.

[image: Table of results]

In the image the results are shown for different data sets (different number of inputs). Starting from 5000 up to 100000 input data and for different number of tasks. You can easily find out (from the table, or you can try by yourself) that if you use Environment.ProcessorCount tasks performs fastest.

As a conclusion, results has shown that using Environment.ProcessorCount is a good practice. Each .NET task will than handle (independently from the programmer) the number of threads that it is going to create (under the hood).

P.S. Environment.ProcessorCount returns integer value (the number of cores of your processor). "Groups Of Data" means also number of tasks created